# Getting the parent terms adds additional empty markup

Tags: custom-taxonomy, html, terms

I am trying to get only top level terms from hierarchical taxonomy called "City". It works fine in a way, because it outputs extra elements...

```
        $cities = get_terms( 'city' , array(
                  'parent'     => 0,
                  'orderby'    => 'name',
                  'order'      => 'ASC',
                  'hide_empty' => true
                   ));
        foreach ($cities as $city) { ?>
        <li><a href="<?php echo get_term_link( $city, 'city' ); ?>" class="button radius"><?php echo $city->name; ?></a><li>
        <?php } ?>
       </ul>
```

Which retuns only 2 cities (and each of them has several child terms)
The returned HTML looks like this:

```
    <li> ... correct data about term 1 </li>
    <li>

    </li>
    <li> ... correct data about term 2 </li>
    <li>

    </li>
    </ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check your closing

your missing the close.  It should be

```
<li><a href=""></a></li>
```

Comment: Many thanks ... It was kind of stupid mistake of mine not to see it, but in the end I missed it :) Again thank you ...

Comment: many of us have done it look saat the same block for ages, then a fresh pair of eyes just spot it like that